# Kivy: making a table widget

Tags: python-3.x, android-recyclerview, widget, kivy

I am working with kivy in a table widget using GridLayout and ScrollView. This is what i have:

https://github.com/Skucul/listwidget

there is a better way to implement it? What about RecicleView?

Comment: RecycleView is more powerfull if you need it.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN, i never used recycle view. How do you create cols and rows with RecycleView? Could you post a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

I got very nice results with RecycleView and KivyMD, which has list elements with Icons and images, etc.

I saw your other repositories too, eg Datepicker and Timepicker, there are similar, there are very similar Widgets in KivyMD, maybe you would consider to use them or even better, enhance them.

Comment: KivyMD looks great! Did you try to freeze your app with pyinstaller? Is your KivyMD app a desktop app? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty,StringProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.metrics import dp

Builder.load_string('''
#:import MDLabel kivymd.label.MDLabel
<Table>
    orientation:'vertical'  
    size_hint_y:0.9
    GridLayout:
        id:header
        spacing:2
        padding:[10,10,10,10]
        size_hint_y:None
        height:dp(48)
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y:1       
        GridLayout:
            id:body
            spacing:2
            padding:[10,10,10,10]
            size_hint_y:None
            #spacing:dp(2)
            height:self.minimum_height

    # GridLayout:
    #     id:footer
    #     height:dp(48)
    #     pos_hint:{'center_y':0.1}

<Header>
    padding:[10,10,10,10]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.theme_cls.accent_dark
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    size_hint_y:None
    size_hint_x:header.size_hint_x
    height:dp(48)
    MDLabel:
        id:header
        text:root.text
<Cell>
    padding:[10,10,10,10]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    size_hint_y:None
    size_hint_x:cell.size_hint_x
    height:dp(48)
    MDLabel:
        id:cell
        text:root.text               
''')

class Header(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()



class Cell(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()




class Table(BoxLayout):
    cols = NumericProperty(1)
    table_content = ListProperty([{"col 1":"row 11","col 2":"row 21"},{"col 1":"row 12","col 2":"row 22"}],allownone=True)
    thead = ListProperty()
    tbody = ListProperty()
    color = [128, 0, 2, 0.8]



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Table, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        for i in self.table_content:
            self.thead =[]
            for j in i.keys():
                self.thead.append(j)
        self.ids['header'].cols = len(self.thead)
        self.ids['body'].cols = len(self.thead)
        for i in self.thead:
            head = Header(text=i.upper())
            self.ids['header'].add_widget(head)
        for i in self.table_content:
            for j in i.keys():
                body = Cell(text=i[j])
                self.ids['body'].add_widget(body)





#create MDTable.py file and save above code
#then import class where to add table widget
#simply use below function pass id where to add table and list of data
    def add_table(self,id,list):
        from table import Table
        id.add_widget(Table(table_content=list))
# list example:[{'head1':'content1','head2':'content2'},###{'head1':'content1','head2':'content2'}]
```